# How to merge two resource files at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, resources

Is this possible to maintain multiple resource file or merge them in such a way so that we have one default file which contains default values for each record and other resource file should override the records according to their requirement.

And our code should check if particular record is overridden or not if it is overridden then it will take overridden value or else it will take from default resource file.

For example :- my default resource file having records

```
           <data name="Common_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>#1892E7</value>
           </data>
           <data name="LoginView_Icon_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>#1892E7</value>
           </data>
           <data name="Here_Text_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>#FFFF1BF5</value>
           </data>
```

other file Resources1.resw have records like

```
           <data name="Common_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>#FFFFF</value>
           </data>
```

other file Resources2.resw have records like

```
           <data name="LoginView_Icon_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                <value>#1892E7</value>
           </data>
```

In this way if we need Common_Color value we can merge default file and Resourse1 file and change Common_Color value from #1892E7 to #FFFFF and have one single file like this and use this file in our code

```
           <data name="Common_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                 <value>#FFFFF</value>
           </data>
           <data name="LoginView_Icon_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                 <value>#1892E7</value>
           </data>
           <data name="Here_Text_Color" xml:space="preserve">
                 <value>#FFFF1BF5</value>
           </data>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to merge two resource files at runtime?

UWP does not provide api to merger resw file directly, And resw often be used to [localize strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest) in UI within UWP platform. We could edit `resw` file with Visual Studio and load the content with following, and we could not edit their content at running time.

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
this.myXAMLTextBlockElement.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Farewell");
```

For your requirement, we suggest you use [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject) file to replace, you could deserialize json file to objects, compare the different and merger then serialize  the new object to json file.